# Computing the array of points describing the area around a curve in GDI+

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

Starting from a curve defined as a series of points drawn by the user (left in figure below), I would like to derive the points describing the area around that curve. To this end I'm using the `Widen` function from `GraphisPath` as shown here below:

```
PointF[] ComputeAreaAroundCurve(PointF[] curvePoints)
{
    GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
    gp.AddLines(curvePoints);
    using(Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 10))
        gp.Widen(pen);
    return gp.PathPoints;
}
```

If I then draw the result, I obtain the figure to the right where of course the intersecting portion (red arrow) is not taken. Any idea of how to compute instead the PointF[] that when drawn would include that portion too?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `FillMode.Winding` when drawing the path?

Comment: Yes, I tried the FillMode.Winding when creating the path but no change. Also please consider that I would like the point array because afterwards I need to perform other operations (like determine whether a point is included within the described area)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use **two** `GraphicsPaths`:

- The **first** one is the one you use to get the **outline** points with the `Widen` call. It has to be in the (default) fillmode `Alternate`.
- After you have returned the outline points `opp` you need to add them to a **second** `GraphicsPath`. This one must be set to `FillMode.Winding`.

The second `GraphicsPath` will fill the full outline including the crossing(s) and will also report points inside to be 'visible'..

```
gpWinding = new GraphicsPath();
gpWinding.FillMode = FillMode.Winding;

gpWinding.AddCurve(opp);
```

Now a `MouseClick` will work:

```
Text = gpWinding.IsVisible(e.Location) ? "Yes" : "No";
```

And filling it will fill all the outlined area:

```
e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.DarkKhaki, gpWinding );
e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.White, gpWinding );
```

[image]